# How to ignore auto generated key in hibernate during retrieval

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, rest

I am using hibernate with restful interface, I have one-to-many relationship between three tables, when I want to retrieve the records in those tables from mysql database (using curl command) I also get their ids (which were auto-generated) but I don't want them to be retrieved, is there any way I can do this?

Here is result I retrieve:

```
[
    {
        "deviceID": "no id",
        "deviceName": "no name",
        "deviceType": "no_type",
        ***"id": 1,***
        "newMeasurements": [
            {
                "measurementT": "type",
                "measurementU": "unit",
                "measurementV": "value",
                "measurementDateTime": "15.09.9898",
                ***"id": 1***
            }
        ],
        "Oldmeasurement": [
            {
                "measurementTime": "12.02.1586",
                "sampleR": "rate",
                "sampleU": "Unit",
                "sampleT": "Type",
                "sampleU": "Unit",
                "sampleV": "noValues",
                ***"id": 1***
            }
        ],
        ***"patientID": 1***
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering to your question I would like to give you a glance/background on few things.
In case of OOP, Almost everything is object and how to identify, compare two instance of same type plays a key role here. There is a concept called equality and identity which is use to identify and compare objects(I hope you are aware of it).

Similarly there is another mechanism in hibernate called database identity to identify/compare two same type instance. Meaning it is a way to determine that the two same type instances representing/pointing to same row. This can be achieved only through identifier which you want to ignore during retrieval.

The bottom line is Id is really mandatory to identify objects since hibernate compares objects based on values but not by its memory location (identity)

**Recommended way to create your entity is**

```
Class MyEntity
{

@id
@column(name=”id”)

//Id generation strategy goes here. 
Private int id;

@column(name=”name”)
Private String name;

Public int getId()
{
return this.id;
}
//Getter and setters of name

}
```

You might have noticed the absence of setter method of ID. Reason is changing of identity is not allowed/recommended. Hope this is helpful!